# AWS SAM: Lambda in nested stack won't pick up requirements.txt

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm building a SAM template that uses nested stacks. My top-level template.yaml has two nested stack resources: base_layer and eventHandler. The base_layer stack creates a lambda stack set that has lower-level functions (logging, etc) that other functions will rely on. These appear to all work as expected.

The eventHandler stack has an SNS topic and an SQS queue and a lambda function that is supposed to pick up events from the SQS queue and insert them into an RDS database (which exists outside the SAM stack).

The eventHandler python does an `import` of `mysql.connector`. There is a requirements.txt file that has mysql and mysql-connector listed.

When I test the eventHandler lambda function in the AWS Lambda console, I get:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'eventHandler': No module named 'mysql'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
+template.yaml
+samconfig.toml
+cloudformation_stacks
| +base_layer.yaml
| +eventHandler.yaml
+code
  +base_layer
  | +python
  |   +lib
  |     +python3.8
  |       +site-packages
  |         +loggingfunctions.py
  |         +otherlowlevelfunctions.py
  |         +moremiscellaneousfunctions.py
  +eventHandler
    +eventHandler.py
    +requirements.txt
```

Requirements.txt has:

```
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql==0.0.2
```

I've tried moving the requirements.txt file to several different places in my directory tree and always get the same result. Why doesn't SAM/Cloudformation build the Python environment with the mysql dependency? How do I solve this?

EDIT: When I follow the instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package-create.html and do a pip install with a target folder in a child of the folder that has the python file, I see that sam build does, in fact, package those files in the .zip file that it uploads to S3. I guess I need to read up on how to tell Python where to search for import files. (And I'm still not convinced this is the *right* way to do this, but it does seem promising.)

Comment: Sorry. My mistake.